# Get all numbers from string, with decimals

Tags: javascript

I need to convert 'KM1+000.321' to 1000.321.

I tried this

```
var string = 'KM1+000.321';

console.log(parseInt(string.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10)) //1000321
```

But that also removes the decimal. How do I write an expression that keeps the decimal?

http://jsfiddle.net/bbn80knc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there will only be one decimal, [this will work](http://jsfiddle.net/q6q44jxz/):

```
var string = 'KM1+000.321';
console.log(parseFloat(string.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''))) //1000.321
```

Note, you need to use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`, to get the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

1. To replace all but the digits and the decimal dot with nothing, use

   string.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
2. To convert to a number with a fraction, you can't use parseInt() but parseFloat():

   parseFloat(string.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''))